# set JavaFX .root styles in css

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to apply several styles (font, font-size) to my components initially via css-file.

(I am using the `SceneBuilder 2.0` from oracle.)

So I added my css-file to the top component.

My css-File looks like this:

Application.css

```
.root {
    -fx-font: 14px Arial;
}

.button {
    -fx-font: 28px Arial;
}
```

My Application.fxml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="320.0" stylesheets="@Application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="MyText" />
      <Label text="MyLabel" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="MyButton" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

now I add a Text-Element or Label-Element to my pane, the font doesn't get affected by the root node. But if I add a Button-Element to my pane, the style for .button gets applied.

I expected the `.root` node would affect the style of any other elements. like in this answered question but it did not work: 
[Set Font globally in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408884/set-font-globally-in-javafx)

can anyone maybe explain what am I doing wrong?

the only way to archive somthing similar is: setting the style directly as:

```
-fx-font: 14px Arial;
```

under `Style` which i wish i could store in a css file.

Comment: Try explicitly adding the `root` style class to your root element, i.e. `<VBox styleClass="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" ...>`. I know when you add a style sheet to a scene that the root of the scene automatically gets the `.root` style class, but I don't know if the same is true when you add the stylesheet to a parent element like this.

Comment: @James_D that would actuallywork, but i dont think thats how it is supposed to work. For the button it worked without setting a style-class. Though I fear i'd encounter a problem if one of my scenes will really need a style-class which might be used for the root element.

Comment: [Button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button) has the `button` style class by default. [VBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#vbox) has no default style class. If you think you may embed this in a scene with a different root, you should pick a style class other than `root` for the `VBox`.

Comment: the `VBox`was just an example. I actually want to use a global css-file which I can apply to any of my root-FXML-Files. The Main-Project is a `splitpane` stored as fxml, on the right side of the splitpane I add some embedded scenes with different roots. So I was aiming to set a 'global'  css which I can apply to any of them. therefore the `.root` part looked pretty awsome, I hope I just did a mistake and someone can correct me. but `.root` work for any elements, right?

Answer (score 6):

I deleted my previous answer. It was not accurate and it was a little confusing.

A container control doesn't have a property -fx-font. So when you define:

```
.root {
    -fx-font: 14px Arial;
}
```

it has no effect at all.

If you want to set the font for all children controls you should do:

```
.root * {
    -fx-font: 14px Arial;
}
```

or if you want to change only specific controls of a container:

```
.table-view .label {
    -fx-font: 14px Arial;
}
```

or all labels of the application:

```
.label {
    -fx-font: 14px Arial;
}
```